# Does coll stand for collection in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have been running into the term coll, and have just been assuming it means collection or list. But we all know what they say about assuming. Just looking for a little clarification.

Comment: // , Can you give us an example of where you've seen it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `coll` is a common name for a collection parameter in clojure code.

Here's the list of [*idiomatic names*](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#idiomatic-names) from the (unofficial) [Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide):

> in functions:
>
> - f, g, h - function input
> - n - integer input usually a size
> - index, i - integer index
> - x, y - numbers
> - xs - sequence
> - m - map
> - s - string input
> - re - regular expression
> - coll - a collection
> - pred - a predicate closure
> - & more - variadic input
> - xf - xform, a transducer
>
> in macros:
>
> - expr - an expression
> - body - a macro body
> - binding - a macro binding vector

There's a similar but shorter list in the [Library Coding Standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards) page in the clojure developers wiki. While not every clojure developer agrees on their entire contents, both are good readings. Just take them with a grain of salt: "*rules are made to be broken*"